# Determine generic type parameters at run-time in Java

Tags: java, generics, gson

```
class Json<T>
{
  @SerializedName( "T's type here" ) 
  private final ArrayList<T> _bucket = new ArrayList<T>( 5 );
  ...
}
```

I'd like to know how (if possible) the generic parameters of a class can be determined at run-time.  From what I've read this is possible with sub-classes of generic types, but I haven't been able to find out how to do it with the type itself.  There's some great info in these links, but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for.

http://blog.xebia.com/2009/02/07/acessing-generic-types-at-runtime-in-java
www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860

What I'm ultimately trying to accomplish, is to get Gson to serialize the '_bucket' variable above, as the class name of type 'T'.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The workaround it to store a `private final Class<T> typeParam` and pass it into the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generic type is not available at runtime in the given example. Generic type information is only available via reflection if it was specified at compile-time—for example, if you defined a subclass `SomeTypeJson extends Json<SomeType>`.

As a kludge, you could guess at the generic type by examining the contents of the `List`, finding the most specific common superclass via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would sub-class this type to give concrete type, and then processing packages should be able to properly resolve type.
Alternatively many packages have a concept of type reference of some kind ("type token"), which just uses anonymous class to provide type information so that deserializer can correctly infer intended type; I don't remember what class Gson uses bit it should have something like this available.

If the only thing you have is a runtime instance then you are out of luck, with the exception of having non-empty List and checking its type (as suggested).